# MPI distributed array view: wrong values when reading input

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi, matrix-multiplication

I have to make a C program that calculates a product between two (big) matrixes.
I have to distribute matrix blocks between the processes, in a block-cycle way.

I'm trying to make the I/O, determining which process has to take which block(s), as follows (all is hardcoded, some checks are missing and the matrix is 3x3 with just 1 process, just to try).

The processes are distributed in a "Cartesian" way (`MPI_Dims_create` + `MPI_Cart_create`).

Writing:

```
// write to file
MPI_File file;

float matrix[3][3] = {
    { 0.0, 1.0, 2.0},
    { 3.0, 4.0, 5.0},
    { 6.0, 7.0, 8.0},
};
MPI_File_open(comm, matrix_file_name, MPI_MODE_CREATE | MPI_MODE_WRONLY, MPI_INFO_NULL, &file);
if (rank == 0) {        
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            MPI_File_write(file, &matrix[i][j], sizeof (&matrix[i][j]), MPI_FLOAT, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        }
    }
}

MPI_File_close(&file);
```

reading:

```
//read from file

int matrix_size;
float *matrix;
int gsizes[2] = {3, 3};
int distribs[2] = {MPI_DISTRIBUTE_CYCLIC, MPI_DISTRIBUTE_CYCLIC};
int dargs[2] = {1, 1};
int psizes[2] = {1, 1};

MPI_File file2;

MPI_Datatype darray;

MPI_Type_create_darray(size, rank, 2, gsizes, distribs, dargs, psizes, MPI_ORDER_C, MPI_FLOAT, &darray);
MPI_Type_commit(&darray);
MPI_File_open(comm, matrix_file_name, MPI_MODE_RDONLY, MPI_INFO_NULL, &file2);
MPI_File_set_view(file2, 0, MPI_FLOAT, darray, "native", MPI_INFO_NULL);

read_matrix = (float*)malloc(9*sizeof (float));

MPI_Status status;
MPI_File_read_all(file2, read_matrix, 9, MPI_FLOAT, &status);
MPI_File_close(&file2);
```

result printing:

```
printf("Proc 0 received:\n");
for (i = 0; i < psizes[0]*psizes[1]; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < dargs[0] * dargs[1]; j++) {
        printf("%.0f ", read_matrix[i * dargs[0] * dargs[1] + j]);
        if ((j + 1) % dargs[1] == 0)
            printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

when running these three parts in this order, I get:

```
Proc 0 received:
0 1 2 
3 4 5 
6 7 1
```

... but I expect the element in the last position of the matrix to be 8, not 1. What am I missing? I don't know if the problem is when writing, when using (in a wrong way) `MPI_Type_Create_darray`/`MPI_File_set_view` or somewhere else.

Comment: you can dump the file with `od` and the right options, or just check its size...

Comment: `sizeof (&matrix[i][j])` is very fishy.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet thank you for your answer, I cannot do objdump to the file ("file format not recognized"), but I checked the size, and it is 516 bytes. I have 9 floats (4 bytes each), so maybe there is some overhead?
By the way, what do you mean by "fishy"? I know it is not so canonical, but I cannot make it work in other ways

Comment: the command is `od`, not `objdump`. By "fishy" I mean suspicious (and by suspicious, I hint it is definitely wrong).

Comment: Oh, new command learned (not-so-experienced user here :)) really helpful, it made me discover that something was not actually good in it. I updated the writing cycles as follows:
     for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                float * buf=(float * )malloc(sizeof(float));
                buf[0]=matrix[i][j];
                MPI_File_write(file, (float * )buf, 1, MPI_FLOAT, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
            }
        }
and it seems to work, the only thing I'm not getting over is that "1" passed as `size` parameter (why not `sizeof(float)`?) and/

Comment: /the other garbage bytes from the 10th to the 516th... I don't know if it is something related to `MPI_File_write`

EDIT - @GillesGouaillardet I don't know how to properly format non-inline code here, but I changed the inner cycle body

Comment: `MPI_File_write(file, &matrix[i][j], 1, MPI_FLOAT, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);` should have done the trick. the `count` parameter of `MPI_File_write()` is the numbers of types (`MPI_FLOAT` here) you want to write, and here you want to write one at a time. FWIW, `sizeof (&matrix[i][j])` is equivalent to `sizeof(float *)` which is `8`, that explains why the 9th element is `1` instead of `8` (and also why there is some garbage soon after)

Comment: Thank you, it all works now! The core of the problem was that I was doing a wrong use of the `count` parameter. Also, using `od` to check the content of the binary file helped a lot. I really appreciated your answers, thank you again!